# How to retain the position of html elements even after minimizing the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Actually, my web page has 2 **div** tags which are vertically separated using **col-md** values. Its like `<div class="col-md-6">` and `<div class="col-md-6">`. Right now both the divs are aligned side-by-side.  [image].

But when I minimize the browser window, then both the divs are aligned one by one.[image]

Code Snippet here:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading text-center">
    <div class="panel-title"><strong>Virtual Document 1</strong></div>
   </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 10; ">
          <ay-treeTable [value]="node1" selectionMode="multiple" (onNodeSelect) = "selectedLeftNode($event)">
              <ay-column field="name" header="Name" ></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="id" header="Id" [style]="{'width': '130px'}" ></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="versionLabel" header="Version" [style]="{'width': '70px'}"></ay-column>
          </ay-treeTable>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <div class="panel-title " ><strong>Virtual Document 2</strong></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 10; ">
          <ay-treeTable [value]="node2" selectionMode="multiple" (onNodeSelect) = "selectedRightNode($event)" >
              <ay-column field="name" header="Name"></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="id" header="Id" [style]="{'width': '130px'}"></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="versionLabel" header="Version" [style]="{'width': '70px'}"></ay-column>
          </ay-treeTable>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question, could anyone suggest me how to retain the position of the divs?

Comment: Setting the columns to `col-6` should make them responsive. Take a look at the documentation on the [grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/). Since you're defining a breakpoint the columns are breaking

Comment: Rather than using `col-md-6` how about using `col-6` ?

Comment: @RaynalGobel, it is giving one by one. It is not working.

Comment: As @Tico said, replacing 'col-md-6' with 'col-6' should work

Comment: share a minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: As @Tico said, read the documentation

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman, I've shared the code snippet that I'm using in my project. I'm looking into the documentation.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap did you use? Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4?

Comment: share css also, so that the issue can reproduce.

Comment: @RaynalGobel,  , I'm using boostrap 4. My css files are very huge. It's not possible to share here.

Comment: So, I tried it on my own setup, and yes. It won't retain layout when minimized. How about changing `panel` to `card` component? Is it possible in your code base? Because `panel` component is replaced by `card` component on Bootstrap 4

Comment: But I can't card instead of panel because panel is perfect suitable in my project. I'm not allowed to change this css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code with the change 'col-md-6' to 'col-6'. I just linked the latest bootstrap css and its working perfect(side by side). Hope this can help you.

```css
.col-6{
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"> 
        <div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading text-center">
    <div class="panel-title"><strong>Virtual Document 1</strong></div>
   </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 10; ">
          <ay-treeTable [value]="node1" selectionMode="multiple" (onNodeSelect) = "selectedLeftNode($event)">
              <ay-column field="name" header="Name" ></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="id" header="Id" [style]="{'width': '130px'}" ></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="versionLabel" header="Version" [style]="{'width': '70px'}"></ay-column>
          </ay-treeTable>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="col-6"> 
        <div class="panel panel-info">
          <div class="panel-heading text-center">
            <div class="panel-title " ><strong>Virtual Document 2</strong></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body" style="max-height: 10; ">
          <ay-treeTable [value]="node2" selectionMode="multiple" (onNodeSelect) = "selectedRightNode($event)" >
              <ay-column field="name" header="Name"></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="id" header="Id" [style]="{'width': '130px'}"></ay-column>
              <ay-column field="versionLabel" header="Version" [style]="{'width': '70px'}"></ay-column>
          </ay-treeTable>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine but it's not 100% responsive. Its working till some extent of minimized brower window.

Comment: oh!! strange.. it works perfect in all resolution for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will work

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-6"> 
      //first content
    </div>
    <div class="col col-6">
      //second content
   </div>
 </div>
```

for more details about this document as @tico suggested.

**Edit**

Even though this is not a good idea but you said the top one is not working in your case.I know this not suggestible but try this once

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"> 
          //first content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          //second content
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Still it is the same.

Comment: I've tried this one also. I've been following the documentation. But the strange thing is that it's not working as per the documentation. I don't know what to do. But people here are simply downvoting. We are all here to learn something.